# Saving HTML Table as xml or json

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm looking for a way to save a table from an html page as xml or json. The current method i'm using save the entire page as and xls sheet and then reads the sheet using Office.InterLop.Excel. I want to skip saving the file and just read directly from the page using HttpRequest. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking to get the table in XML format, or just export the table to Excel?

Comment: @JamesJohnson I just need the XML or JSON, I would like to avoid saving it as Excel

Comment: Is it just a static table, or is the table generated from a server control, like a DataGrid or something?

Comment: @JamesJohnson its at this page http://cbtcws.cityofhouston.gov/ActiveIncidents//Combined.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you'd like to scrape the contents of a web page without File-> Save As?
[Code project has a writeup](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18034/HttpWebRequest-Response-in-a-Nutshell-Part-1) explaining using `HttpWebRequest` to do just that.  Or, you could use the newer [HttpClient](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee).  Once you retrieve the HTML, you'll have to parse it yourself.

In the [MSDN artticle](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee), they're actually requesting JSON directly, so they don't have to deal with parsing, but you could very easily write up a `RegularExpression` to capture the table body.